# useEffect not run when dependency value with ref on an element changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
export const useOutsideElementClick = (
    element: HTMLElement | null,
    handler: (target: EventTarget | null) => void,
    relativeOutsideElementSelector?: string,
) => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (element && !element.contains(event.target as Node)) {
                handler(event.target);
            }
        };
        const modal = relativeOutsideElementSelector
            ? (document.querySelector(relativeOutsideElementSelector) as HTMLElement)
            : (document as unknown as HTMLElement);
        modal?.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        return () => {
            modal?.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [element]);
};
```

when I include this hook in component, when there is a div with ref which disappears and show with condition when some of value with setState change useEffect doesn't run again. I check "element" value in useOutsideElementClick block with console.log. It changes from null to some HTMLDivElement, but useEffect doesn't react

Comment: when i declare const date = new Date(); in useOutsideElementClick an "date" in deps array it works

Comment: Please include the code that gets the element and pass it to the hook

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the hook, so it would return a `setElement` function instead of expecting an element that you get from a `ref`. Ref changes don't cause re-render, and that's why the element change is ignored.

The `setElement` is return from `useState`. Calling `setElement` would cause the a re-render, and would change the `element` that would trigger the `useEffect`:

```
export const useOutsideElementClick = (
    handler: (target: EventTarget | null) => void,
    relativeOutsideElementSelector?: string,
) => {
    const [element, setElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(!element) return; // skip if no element
        
        const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (element.contains(event.target as Node)) {
                handler(event.target);
            }
        };
        
        const modal = relativeOutsideElementSelector
            ? (document.querySelector(relativeOutsideElementSelector) as HTMLElement)
            : (document as unknown as HTMLElement);
            
        modal?.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        
        return () => {
            modal?.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [element, handler, relativeOutsideElementSelector]);
    
    const return setElement;
};
```

Usage - you use the `setElement` as function ref, so when the element is rendered, it would call the `setElement` and trigger the hook.

**Note**: the `element`, `handler`, and `relativeOutsideElementSelector`. are dependencies of the hook's `useEffect`. This means that you need to memoize the `handler` to prevent the `useEffect` from being trigger by the `handler` being re-created on renders.

```
const hander = `useCallback(...)`; memoize the handler
const setElement = useOutsideElementClick(handler);

return (
  <div ref={setElement} />
)
```

You can avoid the need to memoize the `handler` by passing it via `ref` to the `useEffect`'s callback:

```
export const useOutsideElementClick = (
    handler: (target: EventTarget | null) => void,
    relativeOutsideElementSelector?: string,
) => {
    const [element, setElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    const handlerRef = useRef(handler);

    useEffect(() => { handlerRef.current = handler; }); // set the handlerRef

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if(!element) return; // skip if no element

        const handleClickOutside = (event: MouseEvent) => {
            if (element.contains(event.target as Node)) {
                handler.current(event.target);
            }
        };

        const modal = relativeOutsideElementSelector
            ? (document.querySelector(relativeOutsideElementSelector) as HTMLElement)
            : (document as unknown as HTMLElement);

        modal?.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);

        return () => {
            modal?.removeEventListener('click', handleClickOutside);
        };
    }, [element, relativeOutsideElementSelector]);

    const return setElement;
};
```